# SVG image losing elements on mobile

Tags: firefox, svg

My SVG image loads properly while on Desktop, however on Firefox for Android it is cut like shown below:

[image: mobile]

How it should be

[image: desktop]

I have tried optimizing the file, as I exported it from Adobe Fireworks; no luck.

Pastebin of source: http://pastebin.com/jyrTf5kb

Comment: Please add the actual SVG code, otherwise it's impossible to help.

Comment: What are you using to render the file on mobile?  A browser/WebView or an SVG library?  What platform?

Comment: I have edited my post @BigBadaboom this only occurs on Firefox for Android - latest version

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a long shot, but try simplifying the SVG a little.  It is using clip paths for everything when it doesn't need to.  For instance, the first object is defined as follows:

```
<g>
    <defs>
            <path id="SVGID_3_" d="M66.676 498.582 ...snip..."/>
    </defs>
    <clipPath id="SVGID_4_">
            <use xlink:href="#SVGID_3_" overflow="visible"/>
    </clipPath>
            <linearGradient id="SVGID_5_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0.4" y1="792" x2="1.4" y2="792" gradientTransform="matrix(-8.100000e-006 185.5313 185.5313 8.100000e-006 -146838.8125 418.0006)">
            <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#281464"/>
            <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#A863FF"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <rect x="48.1" y="489" clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="url(#SVGID_5_)" width="107.6" height="185.5"/>
</g>
```

when it could be simplified to:

```
<path id="SVGID_3_" d="M66.676 498.582 ...snip..." fill="url(#SVGID_5_)"/>

<linearGradient id="SVGID_5_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0.4" y1="792" x2="1.4" y2="792" gradientTransform="matrix(-8.100000e-006 185.5313 185.5313 8.100000e-006 -146838.8125 418.0006)">
   <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#281464"/>
   <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#A863FF"/>
</linearGradient>
```

It's just a guess, but there might be a bug with clip paths.

Try this simplified file and see if it works any better: http://jsfiddle.net/YFWcg/1/